# Does OnSubmit Run Every Way a Form is Submitted or Just When the Submit Button is Clicked?

Tags: javascript, submit

I have a form that has a normal submit button, but also several ajax methods that submit the form as well.  I need to do some pre-save validation stuff.  Will the onSubmit function be called every time the form is submitted or do I need to manually call the method before my ajax form submissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onsubmit` event only happens when you submit the form manually.

If you call the `submit` method to submit the form, the `onsubmit` event is not triggered.

If you are making an AJAX call using the data from the form, the form isn't even submitted at all.

Comment: `onsubmit` is the handler, the event type is `submit`.

Comment: @RobG: No, the event type is `onsubmit`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`onSubmit` is what you want. If you're using AJAX, you should send the request within this method and `return false` or otherwise stop the default behavior.